# Getting user input from other threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a console application with two threads, the main thread and another thread. The other thread is executed at a certain time (i have used Timer). In both threads i expect user input for example Main thread => give me your name Child thread => give me your age. All i want to do is when the child thread is executed to not mess with the user input from main thread, so after finishing from child thread (getting the user input) to get the user input from main thread. When i execute this code and i am ready to enter name in main thread, the child thread executed and prompts to enter age. When i enter something this input is saved to the name in main thread.
This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

static class ThreadSafe
{
  private static Timer timer;
  static readonly object locker = new object();

  static void Main()
  {
      new Thread(() => SetUpTimer(
         new TimeSpan(20, 07,
             50))).Start();
      Console.WriteLine("give me your name");
      string a = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine(a);
  }

  static void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime)
  {
      DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
      TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - 
       current.TimeOfDay;
      if (timeToGo >= TimeSpan.Zero)
      {
          timer = new Timer(x => { askNow(2); }, 
          null, timeToGo,
          Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
      }
  }

  static void askNow(int id)
  {
      lock (locker)
      {

          Console.WriteLine("give me your age");
          string b = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine(b + "b");
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ahh race conditions are fun-ness. You need to use ManualResetEvents to pause either thread and wait for the other to complete.

Comment: You are really opening a huge can of hurt trying to interact with the user from multiple threads; avoid doing that at all costs. It's better to do all user interaction from the main thread and have other threads exchange user data using queues or events.

Comment: This is a sample code. I use interaction from other threads because i am making a reminder which writes to console that you have a reminder and also waits for user input to snooze or end the reminder

Answer (score 0):

A single `lock` is not going to help you with synchronization. You need to lock around all bits of synchronized code, meaning you need at least two locks on the same object. To prevent interference in your particular case modify main:

```
static void Main()
{
  new Thread(() => SetUpTimer(
     new TimeSpan(20, 07,
         50))).Start();
  lock (locker)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("give me your name");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
  }
}
```

Also note that you want your locks held for as short a time as possible; in your case you're locking while awaiting user input, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: for a moment i thought my problem was solved but the   string a = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(a); is not executed after Console.WriteLine("give me your name"); in the other thread